# Slaves working in mines one able make a politician/ruler see condidtions through his eyes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a story about a slave working in a mine that was somehow able to either with help/technology or esp to get a ruling member/politician to see and experience his life as a slave/miner. I can't remember anything else about the story/book.

Comment: Hi!  This question is a bit sparse.  Perhaps you can fill in some details, like when and where you read the story?  You can look at the [guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for more suggestions of things you might be able to add.

Comment: I know it is vague but this is all I can remember about the story, obviously there was much more. All I can add is that the politician could see what the slave saw as waking visions or hallucinations while also viewing the world through his own eyes too. in Example; he experienced a cave in while at a banquet and reacted accrdingly causing him some embarrassment.  I am writing a short story of my own that incorporates this idea and after completing it I started to wonder if I the idea was my own or if I had read a similar story. I wouldn't want to plagiarize.